# Is there a BrowserDescription for the most recently created browser?

Tags: web, automation, leanft

Previously in UFT I've used the CreationTime property to select the most recently opened browser window. Is there something similar I can use under LeanFT in my BrowserDescription when trying to attach to the most recently started browser window?

Comment: well, not sure if they added something afterwards, but they didn't have this option in 14.00. Is something else launching a new browser and LeanFT is not aware? Can't LeanFT launch it?

Comment: We normally use LeanFT to launch the browser using BrowserFactory.Launch and a BrowserType but there are scenarios where we need to launch Chrome with a command-line parameter and I'm using Process.Start for this. To handle scenarios where it's being started while other browser windows/tabs are already open I'd like to use something similar to CreationTime if it exists, otherwise I'm going to have to come up with a messy fix using the browser title or URL or something like that.